# How to make navbar dropdown with picture select

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying in ASP.NET MVC in navbar put dropdown menu with select language. When I click on first dropdown button all navbar button need to change language. I wrote Language Controller and it works but my problem is that I want to have in navbar only show pictures of country and I try everything and always I see and letters and pictures.

[image]

I want to have only pictures of flag, without ENG.

One example of code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Brig</title>
    <link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main_manu">

        <div class="title">
            <h2>Brig</h2>
            <br />
            <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed" id="navbarMenu">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>

                    </div>
                    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-colapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.ChoseLanguage) <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                    <li><a>@Html.ActionLink("ENG", "Change", "Language", new { LanguageAbbrevation = "en" }, null)</a><img class="demo cursor" src="~/pictures/flag/gb.jpg" style="width:25%"></li>
                                    <li><a>@Html.ActionLink("SPA", "Change", "Language", new { LanguageAbbrevation = "spa" }, null)</a><img class="demo cursor" src="~/pictures/flag/spa.png" style="width:25%"></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>

                            <li>@Html.ActionLink(Resources.Resource.Home, "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink(Resources.Resource.Services, "Info", "Services", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink(Resources.Resource.Gallery, "Gallery", "Gallery", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink(Resources.Resource.Apartment, "Apartment", "Apartment", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink(Resources.Resource.Contact, "SendEmail", "Contact", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })</li>


                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Brig</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I will appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, Can you insert the HTML from the page?

Comment: I added now above in the example

Comment: Above is HTML+razor content. I want to see what razor produce in the browser for a correct answer